# Issue with python on windows10. Use GIT. But cannot access “runwindows.sh”: no such file or directory

Tags: python, git

I’m trying to use GIT to run python. But was not able to set up the terminal on my windows10. After setting up the virtual environment, ran chmod +x runWindows. But cannot access “runwindows.sh”: no such file or directory.Please anybody can help?

Comment: I’m guessing you mean Git? What does Git have to do with running Python? What virtual environment are you talking about?

Comment: Your command don't look like they are made for Windows.

Comment: Alexander, yes, it is Git, which makes the computer as a terminal to run python. Just follow its instruction one by one. I’m new with python. The virtual environment seems to generate some .sh for using.

Comment: Krause, could you explain a little bit more?